# Increasing MAE/MSE values for larger datasets

Tags: machine-learning, regression

first i want to apologize if this is not the best place to ask this. I have a regression model that predicts quality of wine based on 11 inputs. Currently my model has average Mean absolute error and mean squared error results. 
However i use two datasets that have the exact same inputs and parameters. The one dataset has 1600 entries and the other has 5000 entries. My problem is my MAE and MSE values are worse for the larger dataset. Should my model not have better performance with increased training set size?

Comment: hi, wrong place to ask this kind of question, you are right, you should do it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

> Should my model not have better performance with increased training set size?

Short answer: No

Longer answer:

In general to live with the assumption to have more data gives you better accuracy is the right way to think about it. But more data does not mean that it gets easier for your model. It could get more complex. For example you are using a linear regression, but at some point in time you realize that with more data the regression seems to be a exponatial curve.

You also need to check if that new (more) data follows your original distribution. My approach would be that you retrain your model with more data and think about it of a new problem.